# How to convert date string into date in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have formatted date in string format like "07/06/2017 11:23 AM" so I want to convert it into again date format. How to do this?.

Comment: How you have formatted date in string format, use the same way to format string to date

Comment: i did that but doesn't worked.

Comment: Then show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this string class extension

```
   extension String {
    func date(format: String) -> Date? {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
            dateFormatter.timeZone =TimeZone.current
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
            return date
        }
    }
```

use above function like this

```
let date = "07/06/2017 11:23 AM".date(format:"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"
let date = df.string(from: dateString)
```

For more formats: http://nsdateformatter.com/.

Comment: I think you mean "df.date()" not "df.string()"